# How do I pass in a class to make an array of classes?

Tags: java, arrays, class

I want to create a class (Array) that performs different methods on arrays. What I have so far is overloaded constructors for different types of arrays (ints, strings, etc). However this class will also need to create an array of classes, so how could I pass in a class name and have my Array class create an array of that class?

I could just hard code it in for the class I know I will make an array of but I want to make my Array class versatile enough to have this work with any class I make in the future.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for [Array.newInstance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance(java.lang.Class,%20int...))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a generic array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
public class Array<T> {
    private final T[] arr;

    public Array(final int size, final Class<T> clazz) {
        this.arr = createArray(size, clazz);
    }

    private T[] createArray(final int size, final Class<T> clazz) {
        return (T[]) java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(clazz, size);
    }
}
```

which you can call instantiate by using:

```
final Array<String> strings = new Array<>(5, String.class);
```

I would also suggest a different name for your class as `Array` is already used by the Java API.

Comment: What does the "T" mean? and would this code go inside my Array class? So when I instantiate the class in my code elsewhere I can pass in the type and size? 

Also why are you using the final keyword here?

Comment: T is a generic type. You can learn more about them here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

Comment: I've adapted my example so it hopefully becomes clearer to you how you can use it in your class.

The use of final is just a good practice when you don't need your variables or fields to be mutable. It would work even without final.

Answer (score 0):

As @andresp said, you can make a new class with an array as a private field. Another option to avoid having to pass a `Class<T>` as an argument in addition to the type parameter is to replace the array with `java.util.ArrayList`, which functions just like an array with a few differences.

For example:

```
public class MyArray {
    private final java.util.ArrayList arr;
    public MyArray(java.util.ArrayList arr) {
        this.arr = arr;
    }

    // Add your additional methods here.
}
```